# Collision detection in Xcode(swift) won't work, I am trying to set up boundaries in which the player cannot cross

Tags: xcode, swift, collision-detection

I have the SKContactDelegate setup

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
{
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Here I setup the enum

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32
{
    case Player = 1
    case Boundary = 2
}
```

Here I make the player node.

```
let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "testCircle1.png")
    thePlayer = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
    thePlayer.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width - 350, frame.size.height/2)
    thePlayer.zPosition = 5
    thePlayer.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    thePlayer.name = "playerNode"
    thePlayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playerTexture.size().height/2)
    thePlayer.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    thePlayer.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    thePlayer.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    thePlayer.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue
    thePlayer.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue
    addChild(thePlayer)
```

Then I setup the Boundaries

```
ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(frame.size.width - 150, 10))
    ground.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2 - 75, 96)
    ground.zPosition = 5
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:     CGSizeMake(ground.size.width, ground.size.height))
    ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    addChild(ground)

    sky = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(frame.size.width - 150, 10))
    sky.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2 - 75, frame.size.height - 96)
    sky.zPosition = 5
    sky.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(frame.size.width - 150, 10))
    sky.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    sky.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    sky.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue
    sky.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    sky.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    addChild(sky)
```

Then the collision detection

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
{
    print("Contact")
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Boundary.rawValue
    {
        print("Contact")
        thePlayer.removeAllActions()
    }
}
```

I tried putting the print outside of the if statement to see if it was even detecting collision at all, but it wasn't.

I have looked at many tutorials and followed what they did but it just won't work and I only have a couple more weeks to turn this in.

Comment: Why is the player's physics body set to dynamic = false?   That would imply that it is a boundary and will not be affected by physics.

Comment: Omg dude thanks, I feel really stupid right now considering how simple of a fix that was. The reason I set dynamic to false was so that it wouldn't be affected by gravity but I totally forgot about the affectedByGravity function. Thanks man!

Comment: I have transferred the comment to an answer so you can mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the player node

remove this:

```
thePlayer.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

That is setting the physics body to be a boundary and not a body...